# SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2 Export Structure + Data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to export the structure and data in my database into a .sql file to then execute as a query on another machine.

Any ideas on how this can be achieved? I have tried using the database import/export wizards to no avail...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Right click on database, to go tasks, generate scripts. Make sure you choose the option "Schema and Data" for what "Types of Data to Script" when clicking on the "Advanced" button.

Comment: Hello, I think this is were the problem lies - I have the following tabs (Introduction, Choose Objects, Set Scripting Options, Summary and Save or Publish Scipts) under which tab would the schema and data option be?

Comment: It is under Set Scripting Options > Advanced.